# iOS - Swift Facebook Graph Request completion handler - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to make this Facebook Graph request work but I get two errors :

1. Cannot conver value of type '(*,*,_) throws -> Void' to expected argument type 'FBSDKGraphRequestHandler!' - On line #6
2. Type of expression is ambiguous without more context - On line #14

This is my code for viewDidLoad() :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, gender"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler( {

        (connection, results, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else if let result = results {

            PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] = result["gender"]
            PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]

            try PFUser.currentUser()?.save() 


            let userId = result["id"] as! String

            let facebookProfilePictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large"

            if let fbpicUrl = NSURL(string: facebookProfilePictureUrl) {

                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fbpicUrl) {

                    self.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data)

                    let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: data)!

                    PFUser.currentUser()?["image"] = imageFile

                    try PFUser.currentUser()?.save()

                }}}
    })



}
```

If you have any suggestion for how to fix that, it would really appreciated if you could let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using `try` without `do-catch`.

```
let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, gender"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, results, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if let result = results {
            PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] = result["gender"]
            PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]

            do {
                try PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
            } catch let ex {
                print(ex)
            }

            let userId = result["id"] as! String
            let facebookProfilePictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large"

            if let fbpicUrl = NSURL(string: facebookProfilePictureUrl),
                data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fbpicUrl) {
                    self.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: data)!
                    PFUser.currentUser()?["image"] = imageFile
                    do {
                        try PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
                    } catch let ex {
                        print(ex)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

or you can use `try?` or `try!`

```
try? PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
```

But using `save()` method is not good choose. It lock current thread. Better if you will use `saveInBackground` with completion block if you need to be sure it saved successfully or `saveEventually`.
Btw. your code is not very well formatted and really hard to read...